# Problem with pdf preview in LyX

Tags: lyx

I have just downloaded LyX and I have been trying to preview my work as a pdf file. The problem is that I have been getting this error:

> The path of your document
>
> (C:/ ... /)
>
> contains glyphs that are unknown in the current document encoding
>
> ...

The problem then seems to be that there are greek letters in the path and LyX cannot read them. Is there perhaps a solution for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have to avoid greek letters, german umlauts, and whatever strange glyphs in your path and filenames. Even if the OS -- seems Windows in your case -- can handle the non ASCII letters, the texlive and MikTeX installations below Lyx can't.

I avoid even spaces in the filenames and signs like +,#,~, accents, dots (except one), ...

If you'd like to have an explanation or background to this, search for encoding of filenames. Maybe you could start with the manual to the package "grffile".

You can get all the documentation about TeX on you system by opening a command window and typing `texdoc <packagename>`. Wonderful feature.

Comment: Thank you. The problem in my case is that I perhaps foolisly named my computer with my greek name, thus all files bear these greek letters.

Comment: I doubt that all folders on your PC use greek letters. Try if it works if you store your document in say C:\mytexdocuments.